# C# WPF ContextMenu: MenuItem does not react to click

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `C#` `WPF-Application`. In the `XAML` i have a `Datagrid`, to which I have added a `ContextMenu`, that looks like this:

```
<DataGrid.ContextMenu>
  <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}">
    <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <MenuItem Header="{Binding Name}" Background="{Binding Brush}" Click="MenuItem_Click" Tag="{Binding Id}" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
  </ContextMenu>
</DataGrid.ContextMenu>
```

When using the application it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohZP4.jpg

The problem is, that when clicking the color part of the box (which I'm guessing is part of some internal grid) the `MenuItem_Click` event is fired. However, when I'm clicking on the grey part of the `MenuItem` the click event is not fired. Does anyone know why it behaves this way? And is there a way to fix this?

Additionally, it would be great to be able to color the whole menu item, not just the small box inside. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The "Gray Part" is the Context Menu by itself. You have bounded Click Event Handler to Menu Items so it works when you Click on them. It must not work when you click on Context Menu. You can try to remove margins between Menu Items to remove that gray zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to decrease the `Padding` of the `ContextMenu` and the `BorderThickess` of the `MenuItems`:

```
<DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" Padding="0">
        <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <MenuItem Header="{Binding Name}" Background="{Binding Brush}" Click="MenuItem_Click" Tag="{Binding Id}"
                          BorderThickness="0"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
    </ContextMenu>
</DataGrid.ContextMenu>
```

Or

```
<DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" Padding="0">
        <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}" />
                <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding Id}" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Brush}" />
                <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="MenuItem_Click" />
            </Style>
        </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ContextMenu>
</DataGrid.ContextMenu>
```